# Custom listview using button OnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i have created a custom listview with an ImageView, two TextViews and a Button
now i am facing issue when i try to set onClicklistner to that button
i want different method to be done for every button

here is my code for customlistview class
i have used temporary onclicklistner for that button which shows the toast "Bought"
what i want to do is that after clicking the button i have to return the price of the food.

```
class CustomListView extends ArrayAdapter {
public CustomListView(Context context, String[] resource) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_view , resource);
}
Toast toast= null;


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater MyInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View CustomView = MyInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
    String SingleItem= (String) getItem(position);
    final TextView text =(TextView)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.Itemname);
    final ImageView Image= (ImageView)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    final TextView Pricetag= (TextView)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.PriceTextView);
    text.setText(SingleItem);
    switch (SingleItem)
    {
        case "Chicken":
            Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.desert1);
            Pricetag.setText("Rs 300");
            break;
        case "soap":
            Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.desert2);
            Pricetag.setText("Rs 300");
            break;
        case "Fish":
            Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish);
            Pricetag.setText("Rs 100");
            break;
        default:
            Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
            Pricetag.setText("Rs 0.00");
            break;
    }

    final Button Buybutton= (Button)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.BuyButton);

    toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    Buybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toast.setText("Bought");
            toast.show();

        }
    });

    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            toast.setText(text.getText().toString());
            toast.show();

        }
    });
    return CustomView;
 }
}
```

Comment: you can modify your adapter class to work with some custom array of objects (not just string), ex `MyItems` which will contain item name, and price and any other data needed. so you can work it all in one place. back to your question, how many methods do you want to be able to call? you can `Buybutton.setTag()` for the button with some integers, then `onClick(View v)` based on `v.getTag()` you can decide which method to call.

Comment: can you give example with a working code? that would be really helpfull...i want more then 30 methods

Comment: WOW, even that is too much, you will have 1- create 30 method, 2- have an if-statement with 30 `if else` i can show you sample, but why don't you explain the case better (edit the question) and tell us why you need 30 method, we may show you better way to do it, with less methods to implement

Comment: i need to add the pricetag to the total bill and i have almost 30 foods....
i need just a sample for with a listview with button and all buttons function differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the record,** there should be a better way to do this, using food-id or other approach to prevent this, but based on your request, here we go:

**1-** in `getView()` when you get a reference on the button i.e:

```
final Button Buybutton= (Button)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.BuyButton);
```

do a one more step:

```
Buybutton.setTag(10);
```

10 here could be any other number, and you need to find a way to determine which number to use for each button, also it could be a string , ex value of `SingleItem`

```
Buybutton.setTag(SingleItem);
```

**2-** at `onClick()` you need to find out what the value assign to the view (button) and based on this value call the proper method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getTag().toString().equals("xxxxx")){
        doSomething();
    }else if (v.getTag().toString().equals("yyyy")){
        doAnotherThing();
    }else if (v.getTag().toString().equals("zzzzz")){
        doSomething12();
    }
    //and so on...
}
```

this approach used String as value in `setTag()` and `getTag()`
if you use integers, just replace the condition as belwo:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()) == 10)
```

**EDIT:**

If i understand well, then you need to:

```
Buybutton.setTag(SingleItem);
```

and onClick():

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showPriceTag(v.getTag().toString());
}
```

add method `showPriceTag()`:

```
public void showPriceTag(String type){
    switch (type)
        {
            case "Chicken":
                //set the price tag data ...
                break;
            case "soap":
                //set the price tag data ...
                break;
            case "Fish":
                //set the price tag data ...
                break;
            default:
                //set the default price tag data ...
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: It worked ..thank you for your help..i am using it like this as i dont know how to make a custom array

Comment: @SarmadAijaz good to hear that, i will edit the question and add another better way, using same concept but with less work to do, use it if you want